# Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' because it is being used by another process

Tags: powershell, windows-10, hosts

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin
{
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated ' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}

function UpdateHosts {
    param ($hostName)

    Write-Host $hostName

    try {
        $strHosts = (Get-Content C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts -Raw)
        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strHosts)) {
            Write-Error "Get-Content hosts empty"
            exit
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to read hosts file"
        Write-Error $_
        exit
    }

    try {
        $strHosts -replace "[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+ $hostName","$ipAddress $hostName" | Set-Content -Path C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Unable to write hosts file"
        Write-Error $_ 
        exit
    }
}

$ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"

UpdateHosts -hostName local.pap360.com
```

Sometimes, when I run it, I get the following error:

> Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' because it is being used by another process.

When I open up C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in Notepad it's then blank. ie. all the data I had in it is wiped.

My question is...  how can I prevent this from happening?

Like if `Set-Content` can't access the hosts file to write to it then how is it able to wipe it's contents? And why isn't the `catch` block working?

Here's the full error:

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' because it is being used by
another process.
At C:\path\to\test.ps1:36 char:92
+ ...  $hostName" | Set-Content -Path C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:String) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

I also don't understand why it's so intermittent. Is there some Windows process that opens the hosts file up for 1s once a minute or some such?

Comment: As to why the Catch isn't working add -EA  "Stop" to your Get/Set-Content commands.

Comment: Take a look at this post and see if it's the same issue: https://superuser.com/questions/968359/windows-10-hosts-file-used-by-another-process

Comment: @RetiredGeek I agree as a practice, but the file access error appears to be terminating error, so it should trigger the catch regardless. It tested as such on my side.  Note: even with `$ErrorActionPreference` set to SilentlyContinue, the catch still fired, so I don't think his env config is the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if your Firewall or AV software isn't restricting access to the file.
If that is not the case and 'some' other process is currently locking the hosts file, perhaps add a test before reading or writing the file can help:

```
function Test-LockedFile {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName', 'FilePath')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path
    )
    $file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($Path)
    # old PowerShell versions use:
    # $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

    try {
        $stream = $file.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open,
                             [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite,
                             [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
        if ($stream) { $stream.Close() }
        return $false   # file is not locked
    }
    catch {
        return $true    # file is locked
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
function UpdateHosts {
    param ($hostName)

    Write-Host $hostName

    $path = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'

    # test if the file is readable/writable
    # you can of course also put this in a loop to keep trying for X times
    # until Test-LockedFile -Path $path returns $false.
    if (Test-LockedFile -Path $path) {
        Write-Error "The hosts file is currently locked"
    }
    else {
        try {
            $strHosts = (Get-Content $path -Raw -ErrorAction Stop)
            if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strHosts)) {
                Write-Error "Get-Content hosts empty"
                exit
            }
        } 
        catch {
            Write-Error "Unable to read hosts file:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
            exit
        }

        try {
            $strHosts -replace "[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\s+$hostName", "$ipAddress $hostName" | 
            Set-Content -Path $path -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        } 
        catch {
            Write-Error "Unable to write hosts file:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
            exit
        }
    }
}
```